# Sorting data store by date?

Tags: sorting, extjs4

I use ExtJS version 4.0.7. I have a data store with fields: *recordName* and *recordDate*. What I want to do is to **sort these records by date**, however recordDate format is: **d/m/y**. After sorting the records, I need to **bind a grid panel** with these records. At this point **user still wants to see recordDate in d/m/y format**.

As a summary, I have a recordDate field in a datastore with format d/m/y (because user wants to see it in that format in the grid panel), but to sort by date I need to reverse to format as y/m/d without changing the format in the grid panel.

Example: 
**recordDate in the datastore:** 27/08/2012 (and this is what user want to see at the grid panel)

**date format to sort by date:** 2012/08/27

Comment: if you could provide an example (best would be a fiddle link https://fiddle.sencha.com/ ) it would be easier to provide a solution and understand you correctly

Comment: The format of the date isn't relevant to sorting.

Comment: @Hown_ I added an example.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli it is relevant, otherwise it sorts by day.

Comment: If it's a date object, it's not relevant. If you're storing it as a string, then it's not date sorting, it's string sorting. Post your model definition and the date you're sending back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Evan mentioned:

> If it's a date object, it's not relevant. If you're storing it as a string, then it's not date sorting, it's string sorting.

You need to set your model in a similar fashion:

```
Ext.define('MyModel', {
   extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
   fields : [{
       name : 'recordDate',
       type : 'date',
       dateFormat : 'd/m/Y'
   },{
       name: 'recordName,
       type: 'string'
   }]
});
```

Since recordDate will now be a date object, you can use a datecolumn in your grid

```
   columns:[{
        text : 'Date',
        dataIndex : 'recordDate',
        xtype: 'datecolumn',   
        format:'d/m/Y' 
   },{
        text : 'Name',
        dataIndex : 'recordName'
   }]
```